# Using Index/Match on external sheet with delimited cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet, Alpha that references an external spreadsheet Bravo.

I need Alpha's `B2` cell to check in Bravo for all cells in column `A` that contain the string in Alpha `A2`. If it finds a match it copies the value from the `B` column for that row to Alpha `B2`. I've currently got this working using the following formula:

```
=INDEX([Bravo.xlsb]Sheet1!A$2:B$22,MATCH(A2,[Bravo.xlsb]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$22,0),2)
```

..however, I have some cells in Bravo that have multiple strings separated by delimiter that need checking. To complicate matters some of the reference cells in Alpha's `A` column have multiple strings separated by delimiter. Ideally the images below show how I need this formula to work:

Alpha.csv:

[image: bravo.xlsb]

Bravo.csv:

[image: alpha.xlsb example]

So my question is, how can I modify the formula to work with cells that contain delimitered strings as well?

*Update*

To clarify this is how Alpha looks before any formula is run:

```
Alpha.csv (pre-formula)                             

Items                                   Category Group (results)
Oranges|Chicken                         
Ice Cream|Pears|Steaks
```

...and this is how Bravo looks

```
Bravo.csv

Item Categories                         Category Group
Fruits>Pears|Fruit>Oranges              Fruits & Health
Meat>Steaks|Meat>Chicken|Meat>Lamb      Meats
Deserts>Ice cream                       Deserts & Sweets
```

I need B2 of Alpha to take each string in A2 (separated sometimes by delimiter for multiple strings) check through Bravo A column for a match for each string. If it finds a match it adds the corresponding category Group name from Bravo's B column to the Alpha B2 cell.

It repeats this for each string in A2 and if there are multiple strings adds in a | delimiter until all strings have been checked. The result would look like this:

```
Alpha.csv (post-formula)                                

Items                                   Category Group (results)
Oranges|Chicken                         Fruits & Health|Meats
Ice Cream|Pears|Steaks                  Deserts & Sweets|Fruits & Health|Meats
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to simply use the Text-to-Columns feature to delimit your list in your Alpha document. That will allow you to use this formula:

```
=INDEX([Bravo.xlsx]Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH("*"&A2&"*",[Bravo.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A,0))
```

This formula looks for the value in Alpha `A2` with any values before it and any values after it within column `A` in Bravo.

Otherwise you would have to be more specific on what you which category you would like to search, in which case you can utilize `right()` `mid()` and `left()` to adjust your `match()` function.

Comment: I've updated my question to hopefully clarify Melk. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Is there a need to keep the items in Alpha column `A` together? Can you delimit them to appear on separate rows and have each one belong to a category without using the delimiter?

Comment: The sheet has 4000 rows with some items being in 10 or more categories, it would become a bit of a nightmare I'm afraid.

Comment: I think your best bet for this situation would come from some VBA. However, I, unfortunately, am not versed enough in VBA to help here. Good luck with this!